# Bring data frame rows in same order as second data frame

Tags: pandas, dataframe, sorting, rows

I got two data frames:

features:

```
    id feat1 feat2 feat3
r0  a1  1     1     1
r1  b3  4     NA    NA
r2  q7  8     1     1
```

labels:

```
    id target
r0  b3  1     
r1  q7  0     
r2  a1  1
```

They contain both the same id's but in different order. How can I bring either of them into the order of the other one? Is there a way without sorting both of them into an alphabetic order? Like that I only need to alter one of them?

Thanks a lot for any comments!

Comment: `features.merge(labels, on='id')`

Comment: Use this to both dataframes df.sort_values(by=['id']). Or merge them features.merge(labels,on='id',how='outer')